# form redirection in wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, redirect

I want to redirect to php page through php form in wordpress plugin.

```
<form action="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>main-pagination.php" method="GET" id="mainForm">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="strDate" >Start Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="strDate" name="strDate" >
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="endDate" >End Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="endDate" name="endDate" >
  </div>
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

it redirects to main-pagination.php which gets values through $_GET parameters.

but the form on redirection giving 404 error.

both form page and main pagination page in the same directory

form is in index.php of the plugin.

please help me.

thanks

Comment: Are you saying that when you press submit on the form you get a 404? Or does that work, your code does some work and then attempts to redirect the user and that is what is causing the 404?

Comment: it just submits but I am getting 404 error